# How to concatenate multiple result into one row in OBIEE 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, repository, obiee, listagg

I would like to create a report in OBIEE which the data was like this:

```
Table : CUST
CUST_INTRL_ID
1
2
3
4

Table : CUST_ID_DOC
CUST_INTRL_ID       DOC_TYPE_CD      DOC_NM
1                       1              A
1                       2              B
2                       1              A
2                       2              B

Table : CUST_EMAIL
CUST_INTRL_ID       EMAIL_ADDR_TX
1                   xyz@mail.com
1                   ghj@mail.com
2                   yui@mail.com

Table : CUST_PHON
CUST_INTRL_ID       PHON_NB
1                   123456
1                   765442
1                   845322
2                   342315
2                   423424
2                   874534
```

Then I would like to create a report like this:

```
CUST_INTRL_ID  DOC_TYPE_CD  DOC_NM    EMAIL_ADDR_TX              PHON_NB
1              1,2          A,B       xyz@mail.com,ghj@mail.com   123456,765442,845322                                     
2              1,2          A,B       yui@mail.com               342315,423424,874534
```

How do I accomplish this in OBIEE? In SQL Query we can do this with

```
SELECT X.CUST_INTRL_ID
  , LTRIM(RTRIM(LISTAGG(CASE WHEN R1=1 THEN X.EMAIL_ADDR_TX ELSE '' END, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY X.EMAIL_ADDR_TX))) AGG_EMAIL
  , LTRIM(RTRIM(LISTAGG(CASE WHEN R2=1 THEN X.PHON_NB ELSE '' END, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY X.PHON_NB))) AGG_PHON
  , LTRIM(RTRIM(LISTAGG(CASE WHEN R3=1 THEN X.DOC_TYPE_CD ELSE '' END, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY X.DOC_TYPE_CD))) AGG_DOC_TYPE
  , LTRIM(RTRIM(LISTAGG(CASE WHEN R3=1 THEN X.DOC_NM ELSE '' END, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY X.DOC_NM))) AGG_DOC_NM
FROM (
  SELECT CUST.CUST_INTRL_ID
    , CUST_EMAIL_ADDR.EMAIL_ADDR_TX
    , CUST_PHON.PHON_NB
    , CUST_ID_DOC.DOC_NM
    , CUST_ID_DOC.DOC_TYPE_CD
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUST.CUST_INTRL_ID, CUST_EMAIL_ADDR.EMAIL_ADDR_TX ORDER BY CUST.CUST_INTRL_ID) R1
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUST.CUST_INTRL_ID, CUST_PHON.PHON_NB ORDER BY CUST.CUST_INTRL_ID) R2
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUST.CUST_INTRL_ID, CUST_ID_DOC.DOC_TYPE_CD ORDER BY CUST.CUST_INTRL_ID) R3
  FROM BUSINESS.CUST
  LEFT JOIN BUSINESS.CUST_EMAIL_ADDR ON CUST.CUST_INTRL_ID = CUST_EMAIL_ADDR.CUST_INTRL_ID
  LEFT JOIN BUSINESS.CUST_PHON ON CUST.CUST_INTRL_ID = CUST_PHON.CUST_INTRL_ID
  LEFT JOIN BUSINESS.CUST_ID_DOC ON CUST.CUST_INTRL_ID = CUST_ID_DOC.CUST_INTRL_ID
) X
GROUP BY X.CUST_INTRL_ID
```

But this query takes too long and the OBIEE report doesn't load for a long time. Is there any way in OBIEE 11g Repository to perform the same thing, but faster?

Thank you.
Regards,
Jegun.

Answer (score 0):

Doing that inside OBI itself is possible but pointless since this is something that should be done once and physically instead of "at each and every single query and logically".

It's a wrong approach just from a conceptual point of view already